# Android app bundle, force include ABI in all apks

Tags: android, vuforia, abi, android-unity-plugin

I am migrating to an app bundle and am having trouble.

My app uses the armeabi-v7a ABI. This ABI works on both arm and arm64 phones when built as an apk.

When using an app bundle, armeabi-v7a is not included in the generated APK...even though the device is able to support it.

The app I am talking about uses vuforia & unity for AR, but it is integrated into a normal android app (exported from unity).

The arm64 ABI is very problematic (vuforia has trouble with it), so I cannot use it.

IS there a way to force include armeabi-v7a in all generated APKs?

Comment: Can provide more details on your build process, as well as included libraries causing issue, as Vuforia appears to support arm64 ABI: https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Vuforia-Supported-Versions

Comment: The person providing me with the AR files is using version 2018.2.3, so it does not support arm64. (added in 2018.3). I am using gradle-4.10.1, and have the AR files added as a module. I start the UnityPlayerActivity from my app module using an intent. Works as desired as an APK...but not app bundle. I understand that the premise of using the app bundle is so that the user only gets delivered what is needed for the app to run on their device...but the bundle is excluding the v7a ABI..even though it will work on arm64.

Comment: Can't you copy the arm32 libraries into a arm64 'directory' or does that not work due to interaction with components?